# xpath getting value from children

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

From a name  how do I get the sibbling ? I dont wont the nested ones. only the one at the same level. How is this possible?

```
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element instance-id="qk6m4eST" name="image" type="image" index-type="">
        <dynamic-element instance-id="fHkE2dfT" name="subimage" type="image" index-type="">
            <dynamic-element instance-id="jbthDbC4" name="x" type="text" index-type="">
               <dynamic-content>23</dynamic-content>
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-element instance-id="Rb3qRF6N" name="y" type="text" index-type="">
                <dynamic-content>32</dynamic-content>
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-content><![CDATA[C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg]]></dynamic-content>
        </dynamic-element>
        <dynamic-content><![CDATA[C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element instance-id="MFrJW4OR" name="image" type="image" index-type="">
        <dynamic-element instance-id="hjKEtVB6" name="subimage" type="image" index-type="">
            <dynamic-element instance-id="NrY9iZ4K" name="x" type="text" index-type="">
                <dynamic-content>23</dynamic-content>
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-element instance-id="7lG7RuAC" name="y" type="text" index-type="">
                <dynamic-content>32</dynamic-content>
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-content><![CDATA[C:\fakepath\grillat.jpeg]]></dynamic-content>
        </dynamic-element>
        <dynamic-content><![CDATA[C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

This is my code so far. It prints

test...... 23

Thats the value of first nested child.   23

```
public List<PopupImage> getImageNodes(Document document) {
    List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/root/dynamic-element[@name='" + IMAGE_NODE_NAME + "']");

    List<PopupImage> popupImages = new ArrayList<PopupImage>();
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        // node.selectSingleNode("//following-sibling::dynamic-content[1]").getText();
        System.out.println("test...... " + node.selectSingleNode("//following-sibling::dynamic-content").getText());
        createPopupImage(node);
        popupImages.add(createPopupImage(node));
    }
    return popupImages;
}
```

edit: I need every image node and the value of the dynamic value within it.

```
<root>
    <dynamic-element name=image>
         <dynamic-element name=subimage/>
         <dynamic-content>content1</dynamic-content> 
    </dynamic-element>  

     <dynamic-element name=image>
         <dynamic-element name=subimage/>
         <dynamic-content>content2</dynamic-content>  
    </dynamic-element> 
</root>
```

edit2:

To clarify more. I need to pair each image node with dynamic content in it.

Comment: Have you read the [spec on the available axes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes), in particular on the `following-sibling` axis?

Comment: I tried the following-sibling but it gives me the nested ones also. I just need the one on the same level. I will read that though. I have only used google for examples so far.

Comment: `following-sibling` should not give you the nested ones. Can you extend your question to show more of what you're doing so far; i.e. what part of the document are you selecting, and based on that, what XPath with `following-sibling` have you used to get the siblings?

Comment: Ok, I think I'm seeing the problem, but before writing an answer I'd like to state that I cannot quite reproduce the behaviour of your code. Chances are I'm using a different Xml engine than you do, but I don't see how `<dynamic-content>23</dynamic-content>` could possibly be selected by a `following-sibling::dynamic-content` XPath expression, as it evidently is not a sibling of any other element. Is what you are showing us as the source Xml document complete or are there any additional elements in reality? (which would be ok; I just want to know whether I'm missing something)

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a sibling of the "current" element (a `<dynamic-element>`, it seems), the sibling will also be a `<dynamic-element>` in your Xml document, not a `<dynamic-content>` like what you try to select in your code, right?

Comment: Thats the complete document and yes I need the <dynamic-content> node.

Comment: Ok, I still don't quite understand where your current output comes from based on the given document and `//following-sibling::dynamic-content`, but I've provided a possible solution in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/dynamic-element[@name='image'][1]/dynamic-content
```

This selects any `dynamic-content` that is a child of the `dynamic-element` that is the first `dynamic-element` child of the top element, and whose `name` attribute's string value is the string `"image"`.

**And this XPath expression**:

```
/*/dynamic-element[@name='image']/dynamic-content
```

**selects**:

```
<dynamic-content>C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg</dynamic-content>
<dynamic-content>C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg</dynamic-content>
```

**If you want just the text nodes, use**:

```
/*/dynamic-element[@name='image']/dynamic-content/text()
```

This selects the following two text-node children of the elements selected by the previous expression:

```
C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg
C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg
```

You can get the value of the selected nodes by iterating on the returned `XmlNodeList` and obtaining the value of each `XmlNode` object contained there.

Comment: Thank you but i need this element <dynamic-content><![CDATA[C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg]]></dynamic-content>

Comment: @user874774: Yes, this is missing in your question, so I was guessing -- could you, please, edit the question and specify there what should be the selected node?

Comment: @user874774: What you want cannot be accomplished just by evaluating an XPath expression -- XPath is a *query* language for XML documents -- as such it doesn't modify (insert/delete nodes of) an XML document. I will give you an XSLT solution shortly.

Comment: What do you mean? It seems to work. I just want to query the value. not modify anything. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user874774: Done. In your edit you say that you wnat a new document produced -- and specify the exact wanted document. This transformation is applied on the provided XML document and produces from it the wanted XML document.

Comment: @user874774: Might I ask where in the accepted solution the *sibling* you were explicitly asking for plays a role? If you actually don't need the sibling, please update your question to match what is actually being solved here. Otherwise, it will not be helpful but confusing to future visitors. Thanks :-)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, What do you think the most appropriate title should be?

Comment: String imageUrl = node.selectSingleNode("/*/dynamic-element[@name='image'][2]/dynamic-content").getText(); That did not work I have to start from the "image" node. not the rot. Beacause every iamge will need a dynamic content.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I'm less concerned with the title than with the very straightforward question *From a name how do I get the sibbling ? I dont wont the nested ones. only the one at the same level.* in the first line. (Also, the first half of the question seems to be asking for an XPath that's relative to a node already retrieved as a `Node` instance in some programming language.)

Comment: @user874774: There is no `[2]` in my answer!

Comment: I know but 2 will get it from the second image?

Comment: See my last edited answer -- the expression `/*/dynamic-element[@name='image']/dynamic-content` select both elements that you are after.

Comment: I dont want to generate any output.

Comment: se edit again. I know how to query the image node. I have 2 image nodes. I need to extract the value "content1" for the first image node and "content2" for the second image node.

Comment: @user874774: Do you mean you want to call `node.selectSingleNode("dynamic-content").getText()`?

Comment: @user874774: And when you say *siblings*, do you maybe actually mean *children*?

Comment: Yes that was exactly what i needed. :) Will you write the answer or should I?

Comment: @user874774: I'll leave this honor (and the acceptance points) to Dimitre as it was his answer and his repeated inquiring that ultimately led to finding out what you're actually looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, after selecting a `<dynamic-element>` element, you run the following XPath:

```
//following-sibling::dynamic-content
```

Let's look at what this means:

- `//`: Move back to the document root and consider all nodes, nested at whatever level.
- `following-sibling::`: Find a node that is a sibling of a preceding node (i.e. on the same nesting level and with the same parent node).
- `dynamic-content`: This sibling node must be a `<dynamic-content>` element.

This is not what you want as described in your text.

Rather, you want to find a following sibling of the current node. That sibling will be a `<dynamic-element>` element. In that sibling, you want to find a child node, namely a `<dynamic-content>` element.

Hence, try this XPath in your `node.selectSingleNode` call:

```
following-sibling::dynamic-element/dynamic-content
```

Comment: Strange. it works one iteration. The second "image" throws a null pointer.

Comment: @user874774: Well, what is the name of the second image?

Comment: Should be the same  first iteration 
node......org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement@6d9e9816 [Element: <dynamic-content attributes: []/>]
text...... C:\fakepath\images (1).jpeg
path...... /root/dynamic-element/dynamic-content

Second iteration 
node .... null

Comment: The two nodes should be identical.

Comment: @user874774: What is `IMAGE_NODE_NAME`? Is it `image`?

Comment: @user874774: Ok, then in the first iteration, `node` is the `<dynamic-element>` element starting on line 2 of your document. The `<dynamic-element>` element starting on line 14 is picked as its following sibling. In the second iteration, `node` is the element starting on line 14, and it does not have a following sibling, therefore `selectSingleNode` returns `null` in the second iteration.

Comment: @user874774: If you would have expected a different behaviour, please let me know so I can adapt my answer. Your last edit to the question doesn't really clarify where the sibling nodes are used. Do you actually want to transform the Xml document into a different Xml document (as shown in your latest edit), or do you still want to extract a few nodes with your `getImageNodes` method (presumeably for further processing)?